# Why Emacs project C-c p is undefined?

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-projectile

I am new to Emacs. I have installed Projectile.

When I do `C-c p`, it says:

```
C-c p is undefined
```

Wondering what is wrong?

Following is my `~/.emacs` file.

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
                      '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(defvar required-packages
  '(
    projectile
    ) "a list of packages to ensure are installed at launch.")

(require 'cl)

                    ; method to check if all packages are installed
(defun packages-installed-p ()
  (loop for p in required-packages
    when (not (package-installed-p p)) do (return nil)
    finally (return t)))

                    ; if not all packages are installed, check one by one and install the missing ones.
(unless (packages-installed-p)
                    ; check for new packages (package versions)
  (message "%s" "Emacs is now refreshing its package database...")
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (message "%s" " done.")
                    ; install the missing packages
  (dolist (p required-packages)
    (when (not (package-installed-p p))
      (package-install p))))

(require 'projectile)
(projectile-global-mode)
```

**Edit**

My .projectile file

```
-/venv
-*.pyc
-*.pyc~
-.git
-.gitignore
-.DS_Store
```

**Edit 2**

`C-h v` output for `projectile-keymap-prefix` as below:

```
projectile-keymap-prefix is a variable defined in `projectile.el'.
Its value is "^Cp"

Documentation:
Projectile keymap prefix.

You can customize this variable
```

**Edit 3**

I am using OS X 10.10.4. I start emacs from command line `$emacs`. I have installed Emacs using following commands:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa
```

And, very first time (when I launch emacs). If do `M-x`, I don't get `project-switch-project`, rather I get `project-switch-to-buffer`. After switching buffer, I can switch project.

Comment: Do you have a `.projectile` file somewhere? If you aren't within a project, my understanding is that this may not work.

Comment: I should also point out that your `.init` code worked for me in terms of installing `projectile` and getting the commands to function. Try restarting emacs, perhaps.

Comment: Hi, I do have .projectile file in directory

Comment: I see the same behaviour for scratch buffers in Fundamental mode. If I attempt to use C-c p in the initial scratch buffer it doesn't work but it does when I'm editing other files. Could it be that you're trying C-c p in the initial scratch buffer when Emacs starts?

Obviously, it would be nice if C-c p also worked in scratch buffers but it's not such a big issue.

Answer (score 12):

You now need to explicitly enable it and set a prefix.  The steps to enable Projectile with a `C-c C-p` prefix:

```
(projectile-mode +1)
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-p") 'projectile-command-map)
```

This has changed a couple times in 2018.  Boris used to set `C-c p` as the default leader, then changed it to `C-c C-p` to be in accordance with [the emacs keybinding conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html) (bullet #2 mentions it.).  But now it's removed altogether, so you should set it yourself.

Comment: the link to the keybinding conventions you quoted, don't seem to say `C-c C-p` is any different from `C-c p`, so I am just wondering, using `C-c p` feels just as fine. It doesn't seem to break any conventions.

Comment: @DanielDinnyes, `C-c <letter>` for *any* upper- or lower-case letter is reserved for the end user (as stated on the linked page of the manual -- it's bullet point #2).  It is effectively a bug for any library to bind such a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually activate projectile mode in your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(projectile-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Projectile's default keymap prefix is defined by the variable `projectile-keymap-prefix`. You can use `C-h v` to see value of that variable. If not set or is not `^Cp`, you can use the code below to set it to `C-c p`

```
(setq projectile-keymap-prefix (kbd "C-c p"))
```

or any else key binds as you like.

Comment: Hi Tinker, 

It seems that there is `^Cp` variable already set for `projectile-keymap-prefix`. I have added edit2 in my question above.

Comment: Oh, that's strange. Let me see. Could you first execute the command `projectile-find-file` to see if it works. Then use `C-h f` to see the binding keys. As my computer, it is `C-c p f`. So I can use that to execute projectile command. It everything work fine, but you have the problem yet, then I have no idea about this.

Comment: `projectile-find-file` works as expected. `C-h f` also works. But `C-c p f` does not work.

Comment: That's very strange. Perhaps you can `toggle-debug-on-error` and see what happened internal. I am not famillar about that. So sorry for can't provider any more help.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem recently that `projectile-global-mode` doesn't work as how it worked before after I had pinned the `projectile` package to the *melpa stable* archive, which was of the version `v0.14.0`.

The way that `projectile-global-mode` behaved before is that when turned on the keybindings are available from any buffer, but now I can't get it to work when in the splash screen (which is in Fundamental mode) after emacs starts, like Menno Smits points out in the comment.

For the sake of curiosity, I `git bisect` the source code history of projectile to find out which commit introduces this behavior change and finally get [this](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/6986e435e64e2f4ee43bf8093c11e1da5fb266fa#diff-e350afa47840c07f4dbf92840e4f8cfa), which no longer uses `define-globalized-minor-mode` to define the global minor mode but defines the `projectile-mode` as global by default with `(define-minor-mode xxxxxx :global t)`, the difference could be told from the doc of `define-globalized-minor-mode` I think:

> Globally enabling the mode also affects buffers subsequently created by visiting files, **and buffers that use a major mode other than Fundamental mode**; but it does not detect the creation of a new buffer in Fundamental mode. [Source](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Minor-Modes.html)

Not sure if this relates, but this's how I figured it out and hope it helps anyone having the same confusion as mine.